# Is there any special difference between an exe an dll from .net standpoint?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have in the past used .net executables as libraries. I'd just add them to the references in visual studio and I was ready to go. Today I tried the same to a new exe (actually mine) and it doesn't seem to work. When I add it to Visual Studio and try to watch its members on the Object Browser, it doesn't show up anything inside that executable's assembly.

I know the main difference between an exe and dll is that the first has an entry point while the 2nd doesn't. Are there any more differences? I know that unmanaged dll's also have a DLL entry point, do .net have one too?

Also, what might be the reasons that could make my standard exe/dll (with this i mean, not obfuscated or anything extreme like that) not show up anything in the Object Browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work, make sure that the EXE is a .NET exe (assembly) and that it has some public types.

Comment: I think maybe it has something to do with being developing the assemblies in SharpDevelop.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that in the Question, but it should _not_ matter.

Comment: That was it. They were set as private.