# Haxe - compile haxe code to a .NET DLL rather than an EXE

Tags: c#, haxe

Is is possible to compile haxe code directly to a .NET DLL rather than an EXE using the haxe compiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also compile your code and pass in `-D dll` to the haxe compiler:

```
haxe -cp src -D dll -cs bin/cs [class-to-compile]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just rename the file if you want a DLL. The difference between the two in .NET is [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1481112/16391).